# does MQTT API exist to send downlink to lora device?

Tags: mqtt, lora, orange-api

I'm making an application to communicate with LoRa Device.

I found a [guide](https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual_v2.html#LORA_CMD) to the REST API to send downlink.
However, i'm finding MQTT API to do.

Does it exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, at the moment, it really isn't clear what you are asking in this question. Please read the doc on what to include in a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT is used by applications only to consume data in real time.
Device Management action (send downlink etc) must be done by using REST API

regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have additional questions about using LoRa device in LiveObjects platform. Can i notice `device activation`? If i can use MQTT API, it's best for me. If i can't do so, i need HTTP API to get `device activation` datetime or device state. Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Device state notification is not yet available throuh MQTT. You can get device status using REST API. See Live Objects documentation https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual_v2.html#NODE_STATUS and swagger [https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#!/Device_management_-*Interfaces*-_V1/listInterfacesForADeviceUsingGET](https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#!/Device_management_-_Interfaces_-_V1/listInterfacesForADeviceUsingGET)

regards